# Search for key in a LinkedList of IDs and add key to the head of the list if it is not already at the head

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I need some help: I'm making a program that accesses a list and "looks for" an int ID that is identical to its sequence of requests.

Let's say i have a cache with 3 numbers, 
`20 30 10`.

Sequence of requests with 6 numbers,
`20 30 5 30 5 20`.

The program will start with the first number in the sequence of requests and go through the cache, comparing the request with every number in the cache, one at a time and stops if it finds a match. A match will increase a variable `hit`. A variable `compCount` measures the number of comparisons it takes to find a match. If the comparison is more than 1, or in other words if the key found in the cache is not at the head of the LinkedList, the program moves the key to the head of the LinkedList.

Below shows the new cache after 30 is compared with the cache:

```
30 20 10
```

On the other hand, if it is a miss, the program will add the key to the head of the LinkedList.

Below shows the new cache after 5 is compared with the cache:

```
5 30 20 10
```

Below is what I have done so far:

```
static void moveToFront() {

    int key = 0;
    int hit = 0;
    int cacheSize = initCount;

    boolean found = false;

    int[] comparisons = new int[reqCount];

    for(int i = 0; i < reqCount; i++) {
        found = false;
        key = reqData[i];
        int compCount = 0;

        Node curr = head;
        while(curr != null) {
            compCount++;

            if(curr.data == key) {
                found = true;
                comparisons[i] = compCount;
            }
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        if(found == true) {
            hit++;
        }
        else {
            Node newNode = new Node(key);
            newNode.next = null;
            newNode.prev = tail;
            if(tail != null) {
                tail.next = newNode;
            }
            else {
                head = newNode;
            }
            tail = newNode;
            cacheSize++;
            comparisons[i] = compCount;
        }
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < reqCount; x++) {
        System.out.print(comparisons[x] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(hit + " h");
    printList(); //prints the updated list
}
```

There are multiple things wrong with this chunk of code. Instead of adding it to the front, I added the key to the tail of the LinkedList if it is a miss. Also, I have not found a way to move the number in the LinkedList to the head. I figured this chunk of code may be a good place to start from but I'm all out of ideas.

Below is the chunk of code for the Doubly Linked List:

```
class Node {

public int data; 
public Node next;
public Node prev;
public int freq;

     // constructor to create a new node with data equals to parameter i
     public Node (int i) {

        next = null;
        data = i;
        freq = 1;
     }
 }
```

I am also not allowed to use any built in methods. I am open to any thoughts and suggestions. Thank you!

Edit: The comparisons array is the number of comparisons for each of the requests in the sequence of request

Edit 2: The output is as shown below:

```
1 2 3 2 4 1
5 h
List: 20 30 10 5
```

The first line is from the comparisons array, second line is total number of hits and the last line is the updated list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead of adding it to the front, I added the key to the tail of the
>   LinkedList if it is a miss.

The code should be as follows:

```
if(found == true) {
    hit++;
} else {
    Node newNode = new Node(key);
    newNode.next = head;
    head.prev = newNode;
    cacheSize++;
    comparisons[i] = compCount;
}
```

> Also, I have not found a way to move the number in the LinkedList to
>   the head.

After the following loop:

```
for(int x = 0; x < reqCount; x++) {
    System.out.print(comparisons[x] + " ");
}
```

you need to put the following code:

```
for(int x = 0; x < reqCount; x++) {
    if(comparisons[x] > 1){
        int temp = cacheData[0];        
        for(int i = cacheSize - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            cacheData[i] = cacheData[i-1];
        }
        cacheData[0] = reqData[i];
    }
}
```